# Eager loading with belongs_to model (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have these two classes:

```
<?php
class Client extends Eloquent 
{
    public function orders() 
    { 
        return $this->has_many('Order'); 
    }
}
```

And the Order class:

```
<?php
class Order extends Eloquent 
{
    public function client() 
    { 
        return $this->belongs_to('Client'); 
    }
}
```

On my controller, I'm loading orders using:

```
$orders = Order::with('client')->order_by('id', 'asc');
```

It is retieving my order's data, and, in fact, it is executing the eager loading query:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE `id` IN ('1')
```

I can print the order's data using:

```
$order->id
```

But, when printing the client's data, using:

```
$order->client->name
```

It show this error:

```
"Trying to get property of non-object"
```

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
#0 /home/instakioski/laravel/laravel.php(42): Laravel\Error::native(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/home/instakios...', 136)
#1 /home/instakioski/laravel/view.php(386) : eval()'d code(136): Laravel\{closure}(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/home/instakios...', 136, Array)
#2 /home/instakioski/laravel/view.php(386): eval()
#3 /home/instakioski/laravel/blade.php(71): Laravel\View->get()
#4 [internal function]: Laravel\{closure}(Object(Laravel\View))
#5 /home/instakioski/laravel/event.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#6 /home/instakioski/laravel/event.php(138): Laravel\Event::fire('laravel.view.en...', Array, true)
#7 /home/instakioski/laravel/view.php(348): Laravel\Event::until('laravel.view.en...', Array)
#8 /home/instakioski/laravel/view.php(590): Laravel\View->render()
#9 /home/instakioski/laravel/response.php(268): Laravel\View->__toString()
#10 /home/instakioski/laravel/laravel.php(180): Laravel\Response->render()
#11 /home/instakioski/public/index.php(34): require('/home/instakios...')
#12 {main}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dd($order->client) to see if it really is null. It could be null if that particular order has a client_id that does not match an existing client. Also, is your foreign key on the orders table "client_id"? If not, you need to do this:

```
public function client() 
{ 
    return $this->belongs_to('Client', 'foreign_key'); 
}
```

where "foreign_key" is the name of the DB column that holds the key to that orders client.

Comment: Aahh yes! Its is because the client_id doesn't exist anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Debug your result:

Kint is provided so `sd($orders->toArray());`

basically you iterate on the orders collection:

```
foreach($orders as $order)
```

`$order` has one client

```
$order->client->name

++@
```

Comment: Using dd($orders->toArray()); doesn't work, but dd($orders) shows me that my CLIENT is NULL. I'm using $order->client->name inside a foreach($orders as $order)